# Change color of label text when radiobutton is selected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, radio-button

I have a MVC View, with a label and two radiobuttons. What I am trying to do is, when the radiobutton "Dark" is selected, the text color in the label should change to black and when the radiobutton "Light" is selected the text color should change to white.

Model:

```
 public class SetupThemeModel
{
    public bool IsFontColorDark { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult LabelText(SetupThemeModel model)
    {

        return View(model);
    }
```

View:

```
                                        @using (Html.BeginForm())
                                    {
                                        <label>
                                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsFontColorDark, "false", new { id = "Light" })
                                            @Html.Label("Light", "Light Font Color")
                                        </label><br />

                                        <label>
                                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsFontColorDark, "true", new { id = "Dark" })
                                            @Html.Label("Dark", "Dark Font Color")                                                
                                        </label>

                                        <input type="submit" value="Try" class="btn btn-danger" />
                                    }
```

And the label:
`<h1><span class="label label-default h1" id="text" style="background-color:#ffd800">Sample Text</span></h1>`
I tried to pass the color through the label id, but I'm stuck I dont know how to proceed.

Comment: You should use `javascript` or `jQuery` to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You  can write this way :

```
.red{
   color : red;
   background-color: red;
 }

 @Html.Label("Light", "Light Font Color", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "red" })
```

Comment: I want to pass the values through the model